# How do i use the force parameter in visual studio package manager console?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-migrations

I get the following error when i try to create migrations folder in c sharp
when i try to type the following:

```
enable-migrations -contexttypename AccountingContext
```

> Error: Migrations have already been enabled in project 'EFAccounting'.
>   To overwrite the existing migrations configuration, use the -Force
>   parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
enable-migrations -contexttypename AccountingContext -force
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
     `enable-migrations -contexttypename AccountingContext -Force`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Agreed...but I don't see any difference between my answer and answer which is just accepted...no additional explanation too..thats why I was checking with OP...

Comment: If your answer is really not different at all, what's the point of keeping it around.  I realize that your answers were posted within seconds of each other (yours was first even).  But without anything to distinguish your answer from the accepted one, there's no real reason why the OP should reaccept your answer.  The additional explanation could get you that accept, or even upvotes from other users.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you called that command in the past over your `DbContext`, or your are working with an existing DB that was applied migrations before and now you have a table named `_MigrationHistory` on it. You can only enable migrations once for each `DbContext`. As the exception suggest, if you need to overwrite your existing migration configuration you can use `-Force` parameter.

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName AccountingContext -Force
```

In case you have the `Configuration.cs` file, be aware the all changes you did  on it will be deleted.

By the way, why are you using `-ContextTypeName` parameter, are you working with multiple dbcontext? If not, then just run this command:

```
Enable-Migrations -Force
```